# 100 people standing in a circle.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, puzzle

I've got this problem on my Graph algorithms exam and I still can't solve it! Here is the problem:

At first there are 100 people sitting at a round table and neither one is  enemies with their neighbor. Than first night comes and each person becomes an enemy with one of his neighbors. How many nights have to pass until there are no more ways that the group can be seated so no one sits beside his enemy?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Oh okay I'll edit it!Thank you

Comment: What happens on any night after the first night? Do people become enemies with other people besides their neighbor?

Comment: Yes after every night they try to sit in a way so that they won't be sitting beside their now enemy.So than how many nights must pass so there is no more way to sit.

Comment: The phrasing of this question is a bit off.  Let me know if my understanding is correct: On each night, 100 people sit around a table.  Originally noone is enemies with anyone else at the table.  At the end of the first night (**and every night thereafter**) each person at the table becomes enemies with one of his neighbors (*clarify, exactly one or at least one? shouldn't matter*).  Each following day, the 100 people sit around the table such that no one sits next to any of their their (*rapidly growing*) list of enemies.  What is the largest number of nights this process can continue

Comment: Consider the related problem.  Let $G_0 = K_{100}$.  For each $i>0$, let $G_{i+1} = G_{i}\setminus M_i$ where $M_i$ is a perfect matching in $G_i$ such that $M_i$ is a subgraph of a hamiltonian cycle in $G_i$.  How long can we guarantee that $G_i$ is hamiltonian?  (If $G_i$ is hamiltonian, it will certainly have a perfect matching)  (*What theorems do you know about hamiltonian graphs?  Perhaps use something to do with total number of edges or total degree compared to number of vertices.  How many edges will $G_i$ have?*)

Comment: Yes you got it right and they become enemy with only one of their neighbor

Comment: Is this a question from an *active* exam?

Comment: No I just have to redo it as homework

Answer (score 1):

After each night, every person will become enemies with exactly one other person. This gives us 50 pairs of enemies after the first night. (This is because if persons 1 and 2 become enemies, person 3 must become enemies with person 4, and so on around the circle.) An easy way to seat them the second night would be to have each person sit directly across from their enemy. The third night, each person could sit with their enemies 25 seats away in either direction.  You can continue halving the distance between pairs of enemies until they are right next to each other. The sequence of distances would then be $100,50,25,13,6,3,2,$and finally $1$; where someone would be forced to sit next to their enemy. Therefore, you could successfully seat the guests *at least* 7 nights without making enemies sit next to each other.

**Edit:** Thanks to commenter @Jaap Scherphius, I have been introduced to an even better solution. Given seat numbers of $0-99$, label each person by the  number of the seat they sat in on day 1. For any value $0<c<100$ that is coprime to 100 ($c$ and 100 have a GCD of 1), you can arrange each person $p$ to seat $s$ where $s=(p*c)\ mod\ 100$. Coprime values above 50 produce mirror images of other values, so for the 20 numbers below 50 that are coprime to 100, you can successfully place all the people. This allows for a new maximum of $20$ days of happily seated people.

Comment: You can do much better than that. Label the people 0 to 99, and label the seats 0 to 99. For any 0<k<100 that is coprime to 100, you can arrange the people such that seat i holds person i*k mod 100. That's at least $\phi(100)=40$ nights right there.

Comment: Actually, my previous comment gives only 20 seating arrangements, since half of them are the mirror image of the others. But still, it's better than 7.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I have one question about it, though: on day two, both person 0 and person 50 would be assigned to the same chair. How would you get around that?

Comment: $k$ is coprime to $100$, so on successive nights you choose $k=1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, ..., 49$. The arrangement for $100-k$ is the mirror of the one for $k$, so only the $20$ values between $0$ and $50$ that are coprime to $100$ will work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Would you mind if this was included in my answer?

Comment: That's fine by me. Note that this might not be the best possible. I don't understand the comment by JMoravitz, but it hints at another method, and that could give more. My method even allows people to make enemies of both neighbours each night.